# How to use vim easy motion plugin movements with y/c/d commands?

Tags: vim, plugins

I am using easymotion plugin (https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) with vim. 
If you use f/F motions in VIM (with easymotion plugin), easy motion highlights all possible positions when there are multiple matches, that way you can easily jump to the position you want.

But it doesn't work with y/c/d commands, how can I achive that ? 
I have provided an example below for clarification:

`This is some line.`

Say I am working on the above line in vim and the cursor is at the i in "This". If I do "yfs" in vim, I would like easy motion to mark the three "s"s present to the right of the cursor. That way, I can easily yank/change/delete upto the s I want.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, use something like this in your .vimrc:

```
" Find next occurence of a char using easymotion
map  <Leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)
nmap <Leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
```

Now you can do something like `y<Leader>fs` and it will highlight the three s-characters. Selecting one will then yank from your cursor's position to that character.

#### If this does not work

This means that there are other key bindings that are using the same combination. You can check this with `:map` and then look for the key combination you are trying to map to the easy-motion. Removing that keybinding from your `.vimrc` or removing the plugin that created the binding should solve the problem.

If it's the YankRing plugin that's hijacking the y/c/d keystrokes, you can add the following to your vimrc to prevent it from doing that (Check `:h yankring` for more info):

```
let g:yankring_zap_keys = ''
```

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know it was possible. I'll delete my answer then

Comment: Yeah this is pretty handy indeed! But, like with everything in vim, it is a matter of having the right settings in your .vimrc.

Comment: Awesome that works, however is it possible to do it with just f (i.e. without <Leader>)? As using <Leader> makes the keystroke sequence pretty big.

I tried removing <Leader> from the mapping (as shown below), however that doesn't work with y/c/d commands.

```
map  f <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)
nmap f <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I did the same and it worked for me, did you try restarting vim? Maybe even open up a new terminal. The `.vimrc` file is not automatically refreshed when edited.

Comment: @SanderVanhove Thanks for getting back. 
Yes, I did try after restarting. The f motion works by itself or with v (visual mode). But it doesn't work when combined with y/c/d commands. Did it work for you in that case ?

Comment: No problem! Yes, I used the mappings you provided last time and they worked. But I noticed that my `s` easy motion did not work in combination with `y/c/d`. Turns out that there where other keybindings in the way. So I suggest looking at `:map` and removing any keybinding that could interfere with your `f`. These could come from plugins or just your `.vimrc`. Hopefully this solves it for you :)

Comment: Hey @SanderVanhove thanks for getting back. I checked map:

o  f             YRMapsExpression("<SNR>183_", "f", 1)
nv f             <Plug>(easymotion-fl)

I am seeing this in my vim's ":map" output. I am not sure what o means in the first line, but from the second line it seems f is bound to easy motion in normal and visual mode. 
easymotion with f does work in normal and visual mode, but it doesn't work when used after y/c/d commands. Not sure why :( Let me know if you happen to find something.

Comment: Btw, do you happen to know the answer to this (customizing vim key bindings in bash):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143772/how-to-customize-vim-key-bindings-outside-vim-eg-terminal

Comment: Aha that makes a lot of sense! `o` stands for [operator-pending](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapmode-o), this means that it is something to use in combination with `y/c/d/etc`. The YRMapsExpression command is from the [YankRing.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim) plugin, am I right? Did you define that keybinding in your .vimrc or did the plugin set it? You could try to remove that keybinding, or remove yankring, or try to add `omap f <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)` to your vimrc.

Comment: And don't know the answer to that one, but there are no vim keybindings for bash. If you want different keybindings for each individual program, then you need to find the documentation for each of these programs and change their keybindings as stated. There is no centralized way to do that I'm afraid.

Comment: You were absolutely right, it was the YankRing plugin. Thanks a lot for helping with fixing that issue.

Comment: Awesome, no problem! I edited my original answer to incorporate the solution. Would be awesome if you could accept it :)

Comment: Accepted your answer, you rock Sander ! Thanks for your contribution to the vim community in stack overflow.