# How to customize vim key bindings outside vim (eg: terminal)?

Tags: vim, terminal

In my vim editor, I have remapped some of the actions, as I don't like their default key bindings. (For example, I use Ctrl h/l to go to the beginning/end of the line instead of 0/$, as the former bindings are much easier to use.)

I am also using vim binding in my terminal (bash and tmux) and some commands like "less" use vim bindings as well. My customization doesn't work there, so I need to remember my custom as well as the default key bindings, which is pretty inconvenient.

How can I customize the key bindings outside vim (eg: in bash, tmux and less) ?

Comment: so, your question is how can I customize every other tool / OS / terminal to have the same bindings as Vim?  If so, delete this question and ask specific questions about specific tools and specific OS/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applications using readline, you can customize their key bindings in ~/.inputrc.

```
set keymap vi-insert
set keymap vi-command
"\C-h": beginning-of-line
"\C-l": end-of-line
# Line navigation in insert mode.
bind -m vi-insert "\C-h":beginning-of-line
bind -m vi-insert "\C-l":end-of-line
# Line navigation in command mode (after hitting ESC).
bind -m vi-command "\C-h":beginning-of-line
bind -m vi-command "\C-l":end-of-line
```

Reload your inputrc file by running `bind -f ~/.inputrc`

Now, you can use Ctrl+h and Ctrl+l to move to the beginning or end of the line respectively.

This link contains all the readline commands you can use in your mapping: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html

Comment: You have to use a variant to bind to normal mode in the terminal

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to bind in normal mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Although many utilities claim to implement Vim and/or Emacs key bindings, they do not actually involve Vim or Emacs in the implementation. I don't know about Emacs, but Vim doesn't offer any kind of general-purpose key management library, so there would be no way to use Vim from a different program even if one wanted to.

Tmux and Less both have their own completely idiosyncratic key management systems. They are both well-documented. Once you figure out the bindings you want, you can save them in configuration files. (`.tmux.conf` and `.less`, respectively. `.less` is actually a binary file created by `lesskey`; `.tmux.conf` is a text file.)

Bash uses the Readline library, which is a general-purpose library and is also used by many console applications. You can customize all (or at least most) readline-based utilities using a single configuration file. (Normally `.inputrc`.)

The configuration files mentioned above are in your home directory. Most utilities will also consult (or will fall back to) a system-wide configuration file with a similar name in the `/etc` directory. Often utilities have command-line arguments which let you use a different configuration file; that's useful for debugging.

For really detailed information, you'll probably find appropriate manpages already on your system. So you could try, for example

```
man bash
man less
man lesskey
man readline
man tmux
```

There should also be `info` pages for Bash and Readline, which can be easier to navigate. Not all distributions install documentation files by default; you might need to install an associated `doc` package. For example, on Ubuntu and Debian, you'll need the `bash-doc` and `readline-doc` packages.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Right, I forgot to add that. Thanks  Added it now, with some notes.